# Windows 7 - not able to login - not able to enter password

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I am using Windows 7 home premium. I am not able to enter the password to login.

But the space key and the back key are working fine. Even the touch pad is working fine.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "_I am not able to enter the password_"?? Are you not able to type? Is your password is not accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking the little accessibility button in the bottom left corner and bring up the virtual keyboard. You may be able to enter the password using that.